# add parent level in json string

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a JSON string like this:

```
{"field1" : "value!", "field2" : "value2")
```

Now I want to add a parent element like this to get it well formatted as a result:

```
{id: 123, result : ["field1" : "value!", "field2" : "value2"])
```

How Do I do that with JSON.parse or JSON.stringify ?

Comment: It was actually easier than I thought: var obj2 = { "result" : obj1 };

Answer (score 5):

It was actually easier than I thought:

```
var obj1 = {"field1" : "value!", "field2" : "value2")

var obj2 = { "id" : 123, "result" : obj1 };
```

obj2 now holds both parents